# FCM Data message not received by the devices where app is not used in a day

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a backend service and a client android app.
The backend app pushes FCM data messages to the client android app.
My app is able to receive and process the fcm data messages properly if the app is opened atleast once a day on any device.
If on any device if the app is not opened in a day then fcm is not pushing the data message to such device (app).

I thought in such cases where there is no active connection bettween fcm<--> android app, the FCM will call following callback once there is a connection between them.

> onDeletedMessages

but that is also not happening.
For reference attaching the firebase service

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);

        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            processDataMessage(remoteMessage.getData());
        }

        // Check if message contains a notification payload.
    
    }
  

    
    /**
     * There are two scenarios when onNewToken is called:
     * 1) When a new token is generated on initial app startup
     * 2) Whenever an existing token is changed
     * Under #2, there are three scenarios when the existing token is changed:
     * A) App is restored to a new device
     * B) User uninstalls/reinstalls the app
     * C) User clears app data
     */
    @Override
    public void onNewToken(String token) {
        super.onNewToken(token);
        registerTokenWithBackend(token);
    }
    // [END on_new_token]

  

   

    @Override
    public void onDeletedMessages() {
        super.onDeletedMessages();
        
        fullSyncWithBackend();
    }
}
```

Also attached manifest file snippet for the firebase service.

```
   <service
            android:name=".background.service.MyFirebaseMessagingService"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

In the backend I am using following code to send data message

```
  Message message = Message.builder()
                    .putData("event", myEventBodyString)
                    .setToken(token)
                    .build();

            try {
                String response = fbMessaging.send(message);
                
            } catch (FirebaseMessagingException e) {
                
            }
```

Comment: try to set priority HIGH to your fcm messages.

Comment: will that guarantee the delivery?

Comment: I believe you need to look this documentation,may it's helpful. https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/understand-delivery?platform=ios

Comment: updated backend code to send data message with HIGH priority. Still issue is recurring.